# How do I decrease the amount of vertices

Tags: vertices

I am making a donut from a tutorial my the blender guru the ultimate beginner cause I have been using blender for only 2 weeks and i am making a coffee cup but I have too many vertices so I am stuck can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

(If you have already subdivided it) You could use the decimate modifier. Make sure you have it set to un-subdivide and use even values in the iterations bar. You use collapse if you are working with complicated sculpted geometry.
(If you have extruded incorrectly) you can always select the mesh and press w to remove doubles. Or if you are using 2.8+ it is found by pressing alt m in the merge by distance.

If you could give us an image of the problem, we could better understand what your problem is.

Comment: can I give you my file so you can check it out

Comment: If you could take a screenshot of the object in edit mode (to show the vertices and edges) That would help.

Comment: To take a screen shot on mac, press command + shift + 4

Comment: On windows, use snipping tool.