# How do i decrease my vertices

Tags: vertices

Hi am a beginner to blender and I am stuck at a tutorial can someone please I have a lot of vertices and i need to decrease them the video I am watching is

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7w-m13ykLN8
and I am stuck at 8:33 cause the blender guru has fewer vertices then me

Comment: Don't ask the same question! https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162670/how-do-i-decrease-the-amount-of-vertices  If you are not getting answers, or the answers don’t help, then edit your original post with more information and detailing what you have tried that is not working. Read: [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I decrease the amount of vertices](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162670/how-do-i-decrease-the-amount-of-vertices)

Comment: @Wasay Please put some effort into your questions by explaining thoroughly what the problem is and what issues you have encountered. Add images illustrating your scene and settings and state what you have tried to solve the problem and why it didn't work. Also search the site before posting, the same beginner questions tend to be asked quite frequently

Answer (score 0):

You select the area that you want to decrease the amount on and right click if using industry compatible keymap and click unsubdivide. Or you can dissolve the vertices of an area by hitting the delete button which brings up the option menu after they are selected.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162670/how-do-i-decrease-the-amount-of-vertices?rq=1

Comment: this is my file